# Formatting metrics in Superset / Caravel pivot table

Tags: d3.js, dashboard, apache-superset

My Superset / Caravel pivot table slice is displaying the metrics (sum of revenue in this case) in scientific notation.

```
All 4.136578e+08    355190412.0 5.375492e+07    8.226031e+08
```

How do I display it nicely with thousands separator?

I cant find any options to specify Number Format for Pivot Table visualization type. In contrast, when I create slice using Big Number type, there is option to specify Number Format where it accepts D3 number format. I cant find this for Pivot Table.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can change it by :-
select the table .
edit the record .
list the sql metrics.
then choose the metric 
you can fill the D3 format with +, | +12,345.4321

Answer (score 0):

You may changing number in D3 format, here's some guideline :

```
{
  "decimal": ".",
  "thousands": ",",
  "grouping": [3],
  "currency": ["$", ""],
  "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
  "date": "%m/%d/%Y",
  "time": "%H:%M:%S",
  "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
  "days": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  "shortDays": ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  "months": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
}
```

Comment: go to column, edit metrics, find : D3 Format.
this is the refference :
https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Localization.md

Answer (score 0):

It can be defined in your dataset edit panel,
just like this:

[image: dataset panel with a red rectangle around D3 Format field]

then it can be displayed as you designed.